# Remove UiView removeFromSuperview with button action

Tags: uiview, uibutton, ios8, xcode6

I'm having problems with the action of a button ... I do not understand why things are not working and wanted to ask you if you could help me understand the error.

In my viewController I have a button in the selected mode adds a UIView inside another UIView but when the button is brought in was not selected should eliminate the view previously entered, it remains there without doing anything ... I tried in this way, but I do not understand where I'm wrong

```
  - (IBAction)shareActive:(id)sender {
        UIView *checkActive = [[UIView alloc]init];
        checkActive.frame =CGRectMake(2, 2, 11, 11);
        checkActive.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        checkActive.layer.cornerRadius = 5.5f;
        checkActive.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];


        if (!self.condividiButton.selected) {

                self.condividiButton.selected = YES;
            [self.checkCondividi addSubview:checkActive];

                NSLog(@"attivo");

        }else {
            self.condividiButton.selected = NO;
                    [checkActive removeFromSuperview];

            NSLog(@"disattivo");


        }
    }
```

Comment: you always created a _new local instance_ of `UIView` as `checkActive` when this method called. obviously that instance is a totally different one which you have added to your superview during a previous session – therefore when you'd like to remove, you are working with the _new instance_ which has never been added to any superview, and it won't cause any effect.

Comment: In fact ... I found the error ... I created a property in the header file and init the view in viewDidLoad, then in the method of the button in the view I specified the addition and removal from view and now it all works .. thank you very much for the help ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is **one of the many** possible solutions.

I'm sure the others will give you different ideas about how such problem can be also solved.

```
- (IBAction)buttonShareTouchedUpInside:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (!self.condividiButton.selected) {
        UIView *checkActive = [[UIView alloc]init];
        checkActive.tag = 121212;
        checkActive.frame =CGRectMake(2, 2, 11, 11);
        checkActive.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        checkActive.layer.cornerRadius = 5.5f;
        checkActive.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        self.condividiButton.selected = YES;
        [self.checkCondividi addSubview:checkActive];
    } else {
        self.condividiButton.selected = NO;
        [self.checkCondividi.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if (obj.tag == 121212) {
                [obj removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

*NOTE: the original problem can be resolved via many other and probably more elegant ways, but I'm not concerning about those here.*